# How can I search in a database using an integer id variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm developing a CRUD graphic interface.

```
def crudRead():
myConex=sqlite3.connect("Users")
myCursor=myConex.cursor()
myCursor.execute("SELECT*FROM USER_DATA WHERE ID="+id_number.get())
theUser=myCursor.fetchall()
for user in theUser:
    id_number.set(usuario[0])
    username.set(usuario[1])
    password.set(usuario[2])
    biographyText.insert(1.0, usuario[3])

myConex.commit()
```

---

Error:
myCursor.execute("SELECT*FROM USER_DATA WHERE ID="+id_number.get())

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

---

How can i do it to search by the id without having that error?
I've tryed to set id_number.get() and it doesn't return any error but the program doesn't work properly because ID column in database have integer values.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) on how to give arguments to an SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Use placeholder:

```py
myCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USER_DATA WHERE ID=?", (id_number.get(),))
```

Comment: Which is also way more secure than building a query string.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe using f strings could help.

```
myCursor.execute(f'SELECT*FROM USER_DATA WHERE ID={id_number.get()}')
```

Comment: building queries like this is a sql injection risk and that's one of the main ways systems get hacked nowadays.